Remove installed languages with powershell
I am trying to uninstall language packs with powershell.
Those language packs are here:

I want to remove français (France) and Allemand (Suisse) with powershell.
At the moment I use:
Get-InstalledLanguage

Which gives me:

And then I try to uninstall it with:
Uninstall-Language [Language]
Like the microsoft docs:

E.g I try to uninstall de-DE with
$output = Uninstall-Language de-DE

But this doesn't seem to do anything.
Am I doing something wrong? Any ideas?


You'll want to use {Get,Set}-WinUserLanguageList for the user preferences you've shown in the screenshot
